# Displaying notices to users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little issue over which choices to make to move on with my MVC application.
I am trying to make a simple MVC application in which I set up and saved several users into my database. And I also have another application running, for now, I would want this to be a simple console whose main task is to write down the orders into an XML file I make for a user currently existing in my MVC application database. 
What I ask him to do will be inserted into XML as a node content and the file will be saved on the server storage.

In order to display this information to the user when he logs in my site, I am having two choices right now, either `[1]` simply read the whole XML file and display the orders I made to him or `[2]` send him an email notifying him all of the orders I make.

The latter seems a little awkward because I have to send 100 emails if I ask him to do 100 jobs whereas the former burdens on the server storage which supposedly needs to save 1000 XML files if my user number is 1000

Another important issue due my limited knowledge of concurrency is that I don't know how to make my web application always checks for latest XML files being saved on the server for which users that it can read and display the outputs to.

Comment: Is there any reason your not using the database to store the information?  RDMS are used for this purpose and while an XML can be used to back it, it is far from optimal and will get worse as the files grow in size.

Comment: +1 Thank you Justin, third option found! :D